# Line 17 Syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, xubuntu

i have an error that says `line 17: unexpected end of file`.
i know others have already asked this, i tried to do the solutions given to them but still i am having the error. i am using ubuntu server 16.04 LTS. i used nano editor to write my `bash.sh` file. and i also downloaded the `dos2unix` already.

did the command `sudo dos2unix bash.sh`, it says `converting file bash.sh to unix format`...

after i do this i try to run again 
using `sudo ./bash.sh usertest` and i still have an error

my code is very simple just to test an argument:

```bsh
USER=$1 
DATE=`date +%d%m%y` 
if [ -z "$1" ];then 
   echo "Wrong format"
   exit 1
else
   if [ -d "\home\$USERNAME" ]; then
     echo "correct"
fi
```

Comment: Very relevant as well – maybe a better duplicate: [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136/507051)

Answer (score 3):

this is the code you posted (formatted):

```
  USER=$1 
  DATE=date +%d%m%y 
  if [ -z "$1" ];then 
    echo "Wrong format" 
    exit 1 
  else 
    if [ -d "\home\$USERNAME" ]; then 
        echo "correct" 
    fi
```

Hopefully, you can see when formatted this way, you are missing a "fi" at the bottom of the script.

Comment: OMG ! thanks , i missed out on that . now it works

Comment: Formatting helps in multiple ways.