# Bash script: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm running a script in Bash on a Mac and I am trying to split a string with the delimiter being a space into an array. The command I'm running is:

```
array = ($(echo "$string" | tr ' ' "\n"))
```

that returns the "unexpected '('" error. I've tried multiple solutions including

- escaping the parentheses
- putting quotes around the command
- making sure the space wasn't causing the error
- making sure my header is `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Please install `shellcheck` to help you debug scripts: `sudo apt-get install shellcheck`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/21136/how-to-debug-bash-script

Comment: reference to Mac not irrelevant - macs use an ancient version of Bash. Reopen to close as dupe of ultra generic question? No thanks. Please ask on [apple.se] or [unix.se]

Comment: @Zanna  Granted OP uses Mac, but the syntax of such basic thing as variable assignment and command substitution has been the same through multiple versions of bash, and in fact `var_name=word` , that is no-space between name, `=`, and `word` is POSIX-specified, so . . . version is actually irrelevant here and non-Mac specific.

Comment: or use http://www.shellcheck.net/ online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, assignments in shell scripts should not contain spaces between left-hand side of `=` ( the variable/array name ) and right-hand side of the assignment operator `=`. As for converting string to array, you don't need to replace spaces with newlines explicitly, just take advantage of automatic [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting), which occurs when unquoted variables are called:

```
$ string='This is a hello world string'
$ array=( $string  )
$ echo ${array[3]}
hello
$ echo ${array[4]}
world
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is a much cleaner way to do it. Also thanks for the catch about shell script assignments.