# Nesting while loops to build data trees in bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to assign multiple variables to load into a pipeline. I want to prompt the user for values and then read them into variables. My current script is:

```
echo "How many galaxies are you analyzing?"
read n1

i=1
while [$i -lt $n1]; do
echo "Please list galaxy $i."
read gal${i}
echo "How many observations are there for gal${i}?"
read n2
while [$j -lt  $n2]
echo "Please enter observation #$j for gal${i}."
read obs${j}
echo gal${i}
echo obs${j}
let j++
done
echo gal${i}
let i+1
done
```

I would like for there to be a tree consisting of

```
├── gal1
|   ├── obs1
│   └── obs2
├── gal2
│   ├── obs1
│   ├── obs2
│   └──obs3
```

where these values are any alphanumeric combination.

The error I'm getting when I run the loop above is:

```
user@user:~$ bash tst.tst 
How many galaxies are you analyzing?
2
tst.ts: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
tst.ts: line 16: `done'
```

Comment: [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is going to be your friend here - beyond that, I'm not sure what your goal is - a tree of what (files? variables? shell arrays?) and what does "load into a pipeline" mean?

Comment: This is beside the point, but I feel like this is going to be tedious for your end users. Instead, you could have them make a directory for all the galaxies, with one text file per galaxy, with one observation per line, and then parse the directory with your script.

Comment: Related: [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136/301745)

Answer (score 1):

First, indent your code so it's logical structure is more easily viewed (many editors will do this for you, but it's worth doing manually if you must):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "How many galaxies are you analyzing?"
read n1

i=1
while [[ $i -lt $n1 ]]; do
    echo "Please list galaxy $i."
    read gal${i}
    echo "How many observations are there for gal${i}?"
    read n2
    while [[ $j -lt  $n2 ]] ; do
        echo "Please enter observation #$j for gal${i}."
        read obs${j}
        echo gal${i}
        echo obs${j}
        let j++
    done
    echo gal${i}
    let i+1
done
```

Second, the first line should be "`#!/bin/bash`".

Third, line `while [$j -lt $n2]` needs a `; do` after it.

Fourth, using `[` runs `/usr/bin/test` every time. Using the `bash` builtin `[[` (and `]]`) is better.

"I would like for there to be a tree...". It's a SMOP (Simple Matter of Programming), and you will have to arrange the data the way you need it. However, building trees in `bash` is unecessarily hard, when `perl`, `python`, `ruby`, etc exist.

Comment: Also note that the test commands `[` and `[[` need spaces, like `[ $j -lt $n2 ]` and `[[ $j -lt $n2 ]]`

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you for the reminder - I changed my answer.

Comment: "Fourth, using `[` runs `/usr/bin/test` every time" - not AFAIK at least in bash, dash, or ksh (run `type [` if in doubt - it should be a shell builtin in all cases). `[[ . . .]]` still has advantages but probably the *right* operators to use for **arithmetic** comparison in modern bash are `(( . . .))` e.g. `while ((j < n2)); do`