# What does "set -x" do in a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

I am reading a bash script and it start with `set -x`. I googled around and I did not find any single manual which does describe all the flags in details specially `-x`.

My apologies if I sound like someone who did not do his research before asking the question here but I sincerely did not find any information on `set -x`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give a link or post the script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273665/what-does-set-x-do

Comment: It's in a private git repo that I am viewing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36273665/6942873

Comment: Wow been looking for it and you found it on SO itself. Now I don't know wha to do with the question itself. Should I remove it? Or you can post the answer and I can mark it.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21136/how-to-debug-bash-script)

Comment: [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051)

Comment: My goodness: Why *Google* when there is `man bash`? Despite of that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409366/what-is-bash-x  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64110936/bash-x-or-set-x https://linuxtect.com/what-does-bash-set-x-do/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As `help set` says:

```
      -x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
```

It works both in interactive and non-interactive shells, so you can try running `set -x` in an interactive shell to see the effect. Each command that is run is echoed to you first (with `+` signs in front of them to help you distinguish them from most regular output).

```bash
ek@Cord:~$ echo hello world
+ echo hello world
hello world
```

(If you see way more output than you expect an an interactive shell, your shell may be running commands to build your prompt. For example, you'll see about twenty additional lines if your prompt is set up to show information about the git repository you're navigated to, even if you're not actually in a repo now.)

To turn it off run `set +x`. Somewhat confusingly, with `set`, `-` enables a shell option and `+` disables it.

For more information, see [4.3.1 The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) in the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).

Comment: In `man bash` it’s under [SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS/set](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#shell%20builtin%20commands): “After expanding each simple command,  for  command,  case  command,  select command, or  arithmetic  for  command,  display the expanded value of PS4, followed by the command and its expanded arguments or associated word list.”