# How do I get the terminal to stop outputting additional text from basic bash commands?

Tags: command-line, bashrc

I am not sure what exactly is the name of this supplemental text that pops up whenever I am using the terminal, but it shows up when I am running commands. Previously it was not there. I made some modifications to PS1 in my .bashrc recently which may have caused it, but I have reverted .bashrc from the file in /etc/skel and the issue is still there. The effect is something like this.

---

```
user@daniel-acer-ubuntu:~$ ls
+ ls --color=auto
 Desktop   Documents   Downloads
user@daniel-acer-ubuntu:~$ cd 
+ cd
```

EDIT: Restarting my computer fixed this -- but I would still be interested in learning what this supplemental text is and why it's there so I can debug my changes.

Answer (score 3):

You typed mistakenly the command:

```
set -x
```

After that, all commands you enter will be echoed on the screen preceded with a `+` sign (the contents of the [`PS4` "bash variable"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html)). Type:

```
set +x
```

to reset this.

For more information, read the [man page for bash (`set` Shell Builtin Command)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man1/bash.1.html#shell%20builtin%20commands) or see [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167965/what-does-set-x-do-in-a-bash-script).

Comment: Ah yes this was the culprit! Thank you!